# Is there other way to ask reference from interesting answer without enough reputation?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm interested in glass etching with NaOH and find information about it for planning experiments.
I found interesting Loong's answer from [Concentration of NaOH to dissolve glass](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53760/concentration-of-naoh-to-dissolve-glass) but I don't have enough reputation to ask him via commentation (It has to get 50 reputation for commentation.)

Is there other way to ask reference without enough reputation
or try to get more reputation instead?

Comment: Well, you can ask a new question, can't you?

Comment: If you are looking to find a specific user, you ping them by leaving a comment there with @Loong to get his attention. Or as Mithoron suggested, you could post a version of this question on the main site.

Comment: @Mithoron I trird to ask question in main site but I have not gotten any answer. [How to set parameter for etching glass slide's surface with NaOH solution for the shortest time?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88254/how-to-set-parameter-for-etching-glass-slides-surface-with-naoh-solution-for-th) or should I post specifically about asking reference?

Comment: You can get to 50 rep through other forms of contributing, as well. Or get to 15 rep and go to chat. If your question didn't get an answer then maybe there just isn't somebody who happens to know the answer - it happens, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

In principle, there are two:

- Ask a new question that references the original question. This requires your additional question to fit the scope of the site, so a simple ‘Can I have a reference for this please?’ is likely to get closed.
- Visit [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table) (with 20 rep or more), hope the user is active there and if so, ping them. The room of choice is typically the periodic table. Note that only a small subset of users actually visits chat (but you can probably ask a chat regular to comment on the post you are interested in as an alternative).

Of course, there is also the third, most intended way:

- Make valuable contributions in questions and answers and you should reach 50 reputation in no time.

Comment: Chat needs only 20 rep points, just adding that so no-one has to look it up.

Comment: Or, one can just earn enough rep points by improving existing posts (especially by new users). During Winter Bash I got a Brunhilde hat on Mathematics and Physics (e.g. 150+ xp on each) by only editing posts within roughly a week.